# C# SIMD Vector<int> not initialized properly

Tags: c#, .net-core, simd, intrinsics

So I'm playing with SIMD / intrinsics in C#.

Before I report this bug to Microsoft, I'd like to know if I did it wrong.

If I create a Vector on my machine, it has the size 8. I can only new up a Vector with 8 elements. But when I use the vector, only the first 4 elements are stored.

```
var vectorCount = Vector<int>.Count; //8

var vector = new Vector<int>(new []{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8});
// vector: 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

This is especially problematic if I try to compute the min. If 0 is the zero element of a vector, than the min will always be 0!

```
var minInit = new Vector<int>(int.MaxValue);
// .., .., .., .., 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Is this .Net Framework or .Net Core?  You don't need both tags.

Comment: Note that this just seems to be an issue with the debugger. `vector[7]` gives the expected value

Comment: `Vector<T>` does not exist in .NET Framework (only the non-generic `Vector` does), so it's safe to assume this is Core. And I cannot reproduce your result, not in LINQPad, at least (`vector.Dump()` gives all elements).

Comment: @BenjaminGopp There is a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10148) for that already. And related [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/16280) as well. It's already reported:)